# Alsamixer not identifying audio output

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsamixer

I've map a keyboard combination to execute the command `amixer sset Master 4%+` and it does nothing.

I plug my headset via the jack 3.5 port and in pavucontrol/Pulseaudio I can control de volume but not so in alsamixer.

How can I manage to control my audio via alsamixer? If not possible, which command can I use to change the volume with pulseaudio?

Answer (score 0):

assuming 'Master' is listed as an ALSA control element
 
amixer command should work with addition of `--card X`
 
where X = correct ALSA device number
(eg `amixer --card X sset Master 4%+`)
`man amixer` has examples of this usage using the shorter -c option

command `amixer --card X` will list all ALSA settings
same data as alsamixer but in text format

equivalent command for Pulseaudio `pactl set-sink-volume` requires index number/name of sink and adjustment value